# Slow down just one process to regulate CPU temperature

Tags: linux, process

1. I have a program. When it is running, the CPU temperature raise from
   50 to 80 Celcius, which is my major concern.

   I can control the CPU frequency to slow it down, but other processes
   will be slowed down as well which I don't want.

   Is it possible to slow down a particular process without affecting
   other processes to keep the CPU cool?

   My OS is Ubuntu 10.10.
2. I tried to set the priority of the process by `nice -n 15
   myprogram`, and am not sure if that will work. The CPU is 77 Celcius
   high.

   Does `nice` only set relative priority of a process wrt other
   processes? I.e., if other processes are not running, will this niced
   process run fast? I would like to set the process to be running
   slow all through.

Comment: What does this process do: heavy input/output? Heavy calculations on the main CPU? Heavy calculations on the GPU (video card) (usually but not limited to programs that calculate images)?

Comment: The program is pdf2djvu, converting a pdf file to djvu. Is  it heavy IO or heavy CPU or heavy GPU? Do you have different ways for different cases?

Comment: 80º is very very high. I live in a hot place of Spain and the maximus temperature of my processor is ~60º. Open the computer, clean all pieces and change the coolers. I think your isn't the CPU use.

Comment: Try doing both.

Comment: 80° is actually high but not considered extreme depending of the CPU model. most CPU support up to 90°C without issue

Comment: I agree that 80C is way too high. I was having that same problem when I switched to an FX 8350. I was getting 86C and higher on 100% cpu usage. I switched to liquid cooling and now my maximum temperatures are not going much higher than 66C, and that's despite an air flow that is not optimal. I could probably bring it down to mid 50s.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[CPULimit is exactly what you need.](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/cpu-usage-limiter-for-linux/) You start the program, then run cpulimit against the program name or PID, specifying what percentage you want it limited.

The following command limits the process at PID 7777 to 5% CPU usage.

```
cpulimit -p 7777 -l 5
```

Alternatively, you can use the name of the executable:

```
cpulimit -e myprogram -l 5
```

Or the absolute path of the executable:

```
cpulimit -P /path/to/myprogram -l 5
```

Note the percentage is of all cores; so if you have 4 cores, you could use 400%.

Comment: Thanks! (1) Is CPULimit only used for already run process? Not used when submitting a program to run? (2) does it fix the percentage of usage of CPU by a process, or set the upper limit for the process and allow its usage to fluctuate between 0 and that limit according to other processes? (3) I also found that after using CPULimit on a process, there is no way to Ctrl+C to cancel the running, because it will soon return back to run automatically. Wonder why?

Comment: A small caveat about CPULimit: it uses SIGSTOP/SIGCONT to limit the amount of CPU time used by a process (processes exceeding the target CPU usage are stopped; when enough time has passed, the process is sent a SIGCONT and resumes execution). However, there are rare cases in which signals can interfere with system calls, see [the GNU C library manual](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_21.html#SEC362) for details. Since CPULimit sends these signals many times a second, there's quite a chance of interrupting. Not a big problem for running pdftk on a desktop, tho.

Answer (score 9):

You can [renice](http://linux.die.net/man/1/renice) a running process
to give it more or less priority (the so-called "nice value").  Note
that the UNIX priority scale is somewhat counter-intuitive: negative
values mean a process is favored over concurrent processes, i.e., it
has "more" priority.

You can thus try to "slow down" your process given its PID through:

```
# lower priority of a process
renice +1 "PID"
```

Every time you run this, the process "nice value" is raised by 1; you
can use integer values other than `+1` of course.

The command [nice](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nice) allows you to
start a process with a +10 nice value adjustment (change this with
option `-n`). For example:

```
# start a CPU-intensive task with low priority
nice ./cpu-hog
```

However, the "nice value" only affects how much the scheduler favors
running a particular process over others in the system: if your
computer is basically idling, raising the "nice value" of one single
process will *not* stop that process from taking 100% CPU. I quote
from the [getpriority(2) manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getpriority):
(Emphasis added by me.)

> The degree to which their relative nice value affects the scheduling
>   of processes varies across Unix systems, and, on Linux, across
>   kernel versions.  Starting with kernel 2.6.23, Linux adopted an
>   algorithm that causes relative differences in nice values to have a
>   much stronger effect.  This causes very low nice values (+19) to
>   truly provide little CPU to a process *whenever there is any other*
>   _higher priority load on the system._

The reason for this resides in the way processes are run on a
UNIX-like kernel: every time the kernel decides to run a process, that
process has full control of a CPU core for a certain (fixed and short)
span of time.  The "nice value" can influence how often the kernel
scheduler is willing to give a time slot to a process, but you cannot
change the fact that, once scheduled, a process runs undisturbed for a
fixed amount of time.

Therefore, short of slowing down your CPU there is no way to make a
process run slower if there are no other processes in the system that
can contend for CPU access.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to make a process run slow from the beginning till the ending, regardless of other processes?

Comment: @Tim I don't think what you ask is possible; I've updated the answer with more details. Hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: The other reply suggested CPULimit, which seems to do the impossible thing.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about CPULimit - it definitely fills a gap in my UNIX tool set.

Comment: `nice` won't do a thing to keep your processor cool. It is not designed to work like that.

Answer (score 4):

*cgroups* were created for exactly this reason.

http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/
http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/3921001/Setting-Up-Linux-Cgroups.htm

It takes a little while to familiarise yourself with them, and I believe you need root access to set them up, but it can all be scripted. The newer Ubuntus have a .conf file so that you don't have to write your own script. I'm not sure about 10.10.

A nice place to start is in this answer:
https://askubuntu.com/a/94743/170177

Note that cgroups is still under active development so some features may be unavailable in your current kernel.

Using cgroups' *cpu.shares* does nothing that a *nice* value wouldn't do. It sounds like you want to actually throttle the processes, which can definitely be done.

You will need to use a script or two, and/or edit */etc/cgconfig.conf* to define the parameters you want.

Specifically, you want to edit the values *cpu.cfs_period_us* and *cpu.cfs_quota_us*. The process will then be allowed to run for *cpu.cfs_quota_us* microseconds per *cpu.cfs_period_us* microseconds.

For example:

If *cpu.cfs_period_us = 50000* and *cpu.cfs_quota_us = 10000* then the process will receive 20% of the CPU time maximum, no matter what else is going on.

In this screenshot I have given the process 2% of CPU time:

[image: 2% CPU time]

As far as the process is concerned it is running at 100%.

Settings *cpu.shares* on the other hand can and will still use 100% of the idle CPU time.

In this similar example I have given the process *cpu.shares = 100* (of 1024):

[image: cpu.shares]

As you can see the process is still consuming all the idle CPU time.

References:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/cgconfig.conf.5.html
http://kennystechtalk.blogspot.co.uk/2015/04/throttling-cpu-usage-with-linux-cgroups.html

Comment: Note: `systemd` does things a little different. Ubuntu Trusty, for example, seems to come with two services to manage cgroups. I'll update when I know more.

Comment: But you can change the max cpu% when the process is already started, as `renice`?

Comment: `renice` does not change the amount of CPU used, it just changes the priority of the process in the scheduler. cgroups can change the CPU limit at any time. Since this answer was posted cgroups have had all kinds of tweaks added and is very powerful.

Comment: `renice does not change the amount of CPU uses` I know it ;) I just posted as an example of a program that changes things at runtime. Thank you for your reply, I'll try cgroups.